# PHP - Dynamic Page Error

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

Hello I'm new to this dyanmic page system, I have been trying to create a system that has to grab a dynamic page link that I set as key within my index.php then it searches the database for the page_dir.

**Here is my index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('includes/config.php');

$key=$_GET['key'];

$result_array = $navigation->getMenuTitle();
$results = $db->assoc($result_array);

foreach($results as $row)
{
    $query = $navigation->getMenuItemsIndex($row);
    $show = $db->assoc($query);
    if($key == "'{$row}'")
    {
        include("'{$show}'");
    }
    else
    {
        include('login.php');
    }
}

?>
```

**Here are the functions that run within my index.php**

```
public function getMenuItemsIndex( $title_id )
{

    global $db;

    $query = $db->query( "SELECT page_dir FROM tbl_menu WHERE page_title = '{$title_id}'" );

    return $query;

}
public function getMenuTitle()
{

    global $db;

    $query = $db->query( "SELECT page_link FROM tbl_menu" );

    return $query;

}
```

**Last here is my .HTaccess file**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?key=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?key=$1
</IfModule>
```

I'm currently getting a redirection error within the browser. I can't seem to find a way to do this, If someone could help me that would be great.

Comment: Everything about this seems worrying. Why are you including arbitrary files? Why do you have rampant [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/)? This seems scary to an extreme I can't understate. What's the objective here?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you look at how various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) solve this particular problem of routing before you go and re-invent the wheel here.
[Laravel](http://laravel.com/) is a really good example to work from with the [robust routing latyer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing) that does exactly what you want.

Comment: It's my very first time doing this. If you could provide examples backed up with links that would be much appreciated.

Comment: My objectives to make a dynamic page system with normal php. So the user can create pages within a panel and it would change the url to something like... Dashboard without needing to update a htaccess file. I don't want to use a framework becaide my client asked for basic php. So the pages would add to the.navigatikn automatically and then the user can click them to go to them

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "normal PHP" or "basic PHP". It's highly abnormal to write your own system like this when there are dozens that are already field-tested and documented. Giving your client a well documented, standard application that uses a well-known framework is way, way better than dumping some undocumented, mystery code on them that does stuff like what you're doing here. The risks of security mistakes is way, way too high these days to take such a casual attitude towards these things.

Comment: On top of that, there are so many PHP CMS systems out there that do a great job of this already. Please, please, carefully evaluate your options before committing to building yet another one. The **buy vs. build** decision is extremely important. Don't think you're doing anyone a favor by using "normal PHP". You're not.

Comment: Sorry to be so critical. If this was coming from an academic perspective, where you're just out to learn, that'd be fine. If this is for a client, you really need to take a more cautious approach and whenever possible take advantage of the wealth of community code out there that already solves this problem elegantly and securely.

Comment: Could you provide a admin panel cms then? It is for learning me and my "client" are learning he brought the template design I did for him and then we want to make it into a panel

Comment: Can't really make a recommendation here, but [there's a long, long list of options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP). Drupal, Joomla, WordPress, and Magento are probaly the easiest to get support for.

Comment: You see this is more of a staff panel than a content management system. This I'd more of a panel you login too and have pages that include diffrent features like password encryption generator ect

Comment: You could build one of those in an afternoon a more generic framework if you need one, something like Laravel, Yii, Symfony, CodeIgniter, or Phalcon. As an example, Laravel [has authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication) out of the box, there's no need to write any of this.